# How to change Ubuntu on Manjaro, having dual-boot already?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

I have dual-boot Windows 10 + Ubuntu 19.04. I want to change Ubuntu on Manjaro. I did bootable flash usb with Rufus. When i restart PC - I am not getting Manjaro installation as it written in guide. I just still getting my purple screen with choices: ubuntu, win, system setup and one more option. I tried to press f12 while starting PC, chose my UEFI ... [flash drive name] etc, and its opening OS Recovery from DELL Support...

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like the PC is not finding a recognizable boot provision on the flash drive. Beyond that, there isn't enough diagnostic detail to know what's wrong. Just a heads up, though: if you are having difficulty with this, Manjaro may not be an ideal distro for you yet.  It's a rolling release, and you will regularly encounter issues that need solving after updates.  Manjaro is a user-friendly wrapper on Arch Linux.  It's great for normal use, but when it has problems, you are working in Arch, which isn't novice-friendly.  You can get most desktop environments on most major distros.  (cont'd)

Comment: Consider getting your preferred DE on a user-friendly, stable distro.  If you are unhappy with Ubuntu (and Mint), MX Linux is based on Debian Stable, and great if you like Xfce.  If you want a choice of pre-integrated DEs, openSUSE Leap or one of its Gecko Linux spins would be good ones to look at (stable base, user-friendly and well-done implementations, decent repository, great documentation and support, and produced by a big organization).

Comment: Thanks much for describe @fixer1234
I am not really unhappy with Ubuntu(i use it really rare, only to get experience with usage of linux systems, and I want to taste some prog. langs that is better to use on UNIX sys), but I heard(yes only heard) that Ubuntu has some lags/bugs, that is more demandly than other distros, that can be good for programmers. Additionally i have 19.04 Ubuntu, and its not LTS as 18.04, so maybe it is good idea just to switch on 18.04?

Comment: Definitely stick to LTS releases for Ubuntu.  They rarely have critical issues, but even they have enough minor bugs to be annoying.  The interim releases are like beta tests; they're used to get some public exposure to weed out bugs for what will go into the next LTS.  Unless you're developing apps to work with future releases or want to experiment with upcoming features, there isn't a good reason to use the interim releases.  Lagginess depends on the the DE.  The heavyweight DEs, like Kubuntu, can be a little slow on older hardware.  The lightweight ones are fine.